# Individual metadata for clicks and opens in Mandrill API?

Tags: mandrill

There is one part of *Mandrill RESTful API* that I still do not understand. In [the info function](https://mandrillapp.com/api/docs/messages.JSON.html#method=info), that is supposed to return info regarding a send message, we can receive the metadata that was attached to the message. But can metadata be associated to individual clicks?

E.g. If I create a new metadata field called "PersonalID", can I receive the value of *PersonalId* for each individual click so I can understand who in my own application exactly clicked on the link and not just their IP address?

Say this is the response I am getting when I am calling the `info` method.

```
{
    "ts": 1365190000,
    "_id": "abc123abc123abc123abc123",
    "sender": "sender@example.com",
    "template": "example-template",
    "subject": "example subject",
    "email": "recipient.email@example.com",
    "tags": [
        "password-reset"
    ],
    "opens": 42,
    "opens_detail": [
        {
            "ts": 1365190001,
            "ip": "55.55.55.55",
            "location": "Georgia, US",
            "ua": "Linux/Ubuntu/Chrome/Chrome 28.0.1500.53"
        }
    ],
    "clicks": 42,
    "clicks_detail": [
        {
            "ts": 1365190001,
            "url": "http://www.example.com",
            "ip": "55.55.55.55",
            "location": "Georgia, US",
            "ua": "Linux/Ubuntu/Chrome/Chrome 28.0.1500.53"
        }
    ],
    "state": "sent",
    "metadata": {
        "user_id": "123",
        "website": "www.example.com"
    },
    "smtp_events": [
        {
            "ts": 1365190001,
            "type": "sent",
            "diag": "250 OK"
        }
    ]
}
```

The vague part for me is that in the above response we have an array of opens and clicks but in the end, there are only two metadata values (`user_id` and `website`) that are associated with the entire response. So how do we know which click record is this `user_id` connected to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand, the user_id is not associated with a click or open. It is an attribute of the message itself. with custom metadata, you could define a unique user id for each message sent on a per recipient basis. Check this link https://mandrill.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/205582417-Using-Custom-Message-Metadata for more info.

so you could have a user_id returned from the info api call, even if the user did not click or open the email.

HTH,